# django - How to upload file to local and remote server directory at same time

Tags: django, django-models, django-file-upload

I am implementing a feature in django where file uploaded by user should be saved in both local system and remote server location also.

I am able to do both the process individually but not together.

Is there any way we can upload a file to both the location local and remote?

Django version - 3.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify storage for each FileField ([doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.storage)) So create two FileField fields in your model and set required storage for each one.

Example if your default storage is local and your remote storage's name is S3Storage:

```py
class MyModel(models.Model):
    local_copy = models.FileField(upload_to="uploads")
    remote_copy = models.FileField(upload_to="uploads", storage=S3Storage)
```